# is it possible to directly call using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

is it possible to directly start a call(sim) using flutter for both android and ios?

I used this package ([ussd_service)](https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service) for android and worked perfectly.
but this package does not support ios

Comment: Check https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller for  phone calls

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this package can not directly call, it redirect the number to a phone

Comment: On iOS you can only open `tel` urls. Using `tel` urls for USSD numbers is not supported.